# Trying to clone my 500GB HDD to a 250GB SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, clone

I am trying to clone my whole Ubuntu OS to a new SSD. I was following [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6PekWCxcOAI) video. To check to which disk I had to clone, I ran the `lsblk` command.

[image: lsblk command result]

According to this, It seems that sda is my current HDD, and sdb is my current SSD. I then tried to run the following command: `dd if =/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb`. But when I did this, it ran for a while and then gave me an error, that the sdb drive does not have sufficient memory. What I suspect has happened is that the dd command tried to clone my *entire* mounted volume on the HDD (So the whole 495GB, including empty space) to my 250GB SSD. This is not what I meant to do, so now my question is:

*How do I clone my Ubuntu OS + relevant files, but **not** empty space to my new SSD?*

(BTW I've already re-formatted my SSD after my failed attempt to clone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please do not clone disks/images to SSDs using `dd` (regarding wear leveling, etc), especially when your source OS is running . I would recommend cloning your existing OS with `CloneZilla` or `System Rescue CD`. Both live systems offer good tools to solve your problem!

Comment: Clonezilla does not have the functionality to Clone a Bigger HDD to a smaller SSD, you need to resize your partition first and I do not know how to proceed (Linux beginner here).